# Convert Einstein Summation to Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors

I am wondering if the following summation has a matrix multiplication/contracted form:

$$B_{ij}=\sum_{k,l}A_{ik}A_{jk}A_{kl}A_{li}A_{lj}$$

In the way that $B_{ij}=\sum_{k,l}A_{ik}A_{kl}A_{lj}$ is really $B=A^3$. If it helps, $A$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because you have three $k$ indices and three $l$ indices.  In Einstein summation you normally have only two of any index you are summing over.

General matrix multiplication $C=DE$ can be represented as $C_{ij}=\sum_kD_{ik}E_{kj}$.  In Einstein summation this is $C_{ij}=D_{ik}E_{kj}$  You need the second index of the first matrix to match the first index of the second, but for a symmetric matrix you can reverse them because that is just taking the transpose of the matrix.  If you get four summation indices (two of each) in a correct configuration and one each of $i,j$ you will have $B=A^5$

Comment: What if we have $B_{ij}=\sum_{k,l} A_{ik}A_{jk}A_{kl}A_{kl}A_{li}A_{lj}$? I know it isn't standard, but there is no rule that einstein notation necesssarily has 2 (or even) indices. It is quite common to see $A_{kk}B_{ki}$ in physics for example, and there is a contracted form for that.

Comment: I did physics many years ago, but I never saw more than two indices being contracted at once.  The only close example I can think of is the Riemann curvature scalar, which is a contraction of all four indices of the curvature tensor, but that went through two contractions, one to get to two indices, then another in a different step to get the scalar.